# How to retain props or state in a react component?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-state-management

I have a component, compA that receives props as an array and uses it to display an element. I need the ids that come down to compA as a prop to be appended to the array idsToDisplay which out replacing the previous state.

```
const compA = (ids) => { 
  cost [idsToDisplay, setIdsToDisplay] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    /* I need both id-123 and id-456 here */
    /* so idsToDisplay should ['id-123','id-456'] once both component calls has been finished.*/
    /* Tried setIdsToDisplay([...idsToDisplay, ids]); But it causes the max depth update 
      warning.*/
  },[idsToDisplay,ids]
}

<compA ids={["id-123"]} />
<compA ids={["id-456"]} />
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: This really sounds like a XY problem. Why do you need this behavior? is compA called from multiple different places?

Comment: However to achieve this I think a good way would be to use redux or something similar and on the places you would send the prop to compA, you instead add the ids to the store, and on the component you subscribe to the store

Comment: _it causes the max depth update warning_ <--- please try removing `idsToDisplay` from the dependency array of the `useEffect`. Simply have `ids` (the prop) & within `useEffect` you are able to `setIdsToDisplay`. For the render, loop through `idsToDisplay` - so, when there only one `id` only one `compA` will render; but when the second id is passed through the prop the two `compA` will be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but there are a few thing I might remove/add that would improve this snippet, and solve your problem all together.

1. Either wrap the ids-s into '{}' or replace it to props, and after that you can access it as `props.ids`
2. Not sure what is the logic that maybe `idsToDisplay` is not needed in the dependency list
3. You can have just one component, and add multiple id-s there

Something like this:

```
const compA = ({ids}) => {
    const [idsToDisplay, setIdsToDisplay] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
    setIdsToDisplay(ids);
    }, [ids]);
}

<compA ids={["id-123", "id-456"]}/>
```